# PHP Associative Array Strucuture

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any thing wrong with this array?

```
$selects = array(
    "getmoney1" => $money["Dimes"],
    "getmoney2" => $money["Nickels"],
    "getmoney3" => $money["Quarters"]
);
```

I am learning, and I want to know more, and how to do it right.

Comment: Nothing wrong per se, syntax-wise. Do you have any problems with it? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You should ask a concrete question. You could explain, for instance, why you think it might be wrong, it will pose an answerable question.

Comment: Why i think it might be wrong, I am a newb, and a lot of my code could be wrong, that's the process of learning-right?
That's why I asked the question, if I knew the answer I would not have asked the question.
If put a lot of info on any given question, people complain they can't decipher what I am asking for..., I put a one liner and people say ask a concrete question.
Anyhow, thank you Tim.

Comment: A simple construct like an array initialization can often be "acceptable" for the parser but still be wrong (or suboptimal) in the context of your problem. Context matters.

Comment: I will keep note of that  VolkerK, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this declaration. However it does assume the existence of an array named $money, and that $money["Dimes"], etc. are all set.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically nothing wrong, but what on earth would the point of it be?

The original array $money would be easier to work with, I suspect.

But I agree with the commenter above - not enough information to go on.